# where do I place simple pages in a django application?

Tags: python, django

I new in django, but I am really old in web developpement.
My question is about how to properrly organize your project into a django project. I am about to build my first web site in django and i have the following question :

I want a contact page in my website? basically it's a form/view/template, but where do I create that ? should I create a whole new app?

Comment: Please check out [this similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529921/guide-in-organizing-large-django-projects)

Answer (score 0):

Django projects deliver functionality through apps. A project is the configuration holding your chosen apps together. It's highly likely you'll need to write at least one app yourself. Your app will have models, views and forms.

There are a number of projects that can help bootstrap your project. See the [matrix on djangopackages.com](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/bootstraps/) related to boostrapping.

[Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) is a good application bootstrapping tool providing a standard project layout,  starter projects, reusable apps and default templates.

The authors of [Two Scoops of Django](https://django.2scoops.org/) have a [layout on GitHub](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project) which is focused on the environment and file/directory layout.